# Show multiple notification

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, android-service

I am trying to implement a remainder concept in my app which airs a TV channel. Concept is that the user can set remainder for certain TV programs and the app shows a notification 5mins before the program airs on the channel. I am using the combination of `AlarmManager`, `BroadcastReceiver` and Service to handle the notification part.

**Requirement:** Show separate notification for different remainders. i.e. when user sets remainder for 15:26 and 15:27 then the app must show two notifications at 15:21 and 15:22

**Problem:** I am getting only one notification which is updated for all other remainders. i.e. app shows notification for 15:26 remainder and same notification is updated for 15:27

So friends help me with my problem.

Following is the just the sample app to perform above mentioned task:

[image]

Here are my classes:

*MainActivity.java*

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

TextView time1, time2, time3, time4, time5, time6;
Button button1, button2, button3, button4, button5, button6;
Intent intent;
String endTime;

AlarmManager alarmManager;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);

    time1 = findViewById(R.id.time1);
    button1 = findViewById(R.id.button1);
    time2 = findViewById(R.id.time2);
    button2 = findViewById(R.id.button2);
    time3 = findViewById(R.id.time3);
    button3 = findViewById(R.id.button3);
    time4 = findViewById(R.id.time4);
    button4 = findViewById(R.id.button4);
    time5 = findViewById(R.id.time5);
    button5 = findViewById(R.id.button5);
    time6 = findViewById(R.id.time6);
    button6 = findViewById(R.id.button6);

    time1.setText("15:26");
    time2.setText("15:27");
    time3.setText("15:28");
    time4.setText("15:29");
    time5.setText("15:30");
    time6.setText("15:31");

    button1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            Intent intent = new Intent("com.newitventure.remainder.START");
            int id = (int) System.currentTimeMillis();
            intent.setClass(MainActivity.this, ServiceRestarterBroadcastReceivers.class);
            intent.putExtra("id", id);
            intent.putExtra("time", time1.getText().toString());
            PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(MainActivity.this, id, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

            alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, System.currentTimeMillis(), 60 * 1000, pi);
        }
    });

    button2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent intent = new Intent("com.newitventure.remainder.START");
            int id = (int) System.currentTimeMillis();
            intent.setClass(MainActivity.this, ServiceRestarterBroadcastReceivers.class);
            intent.putExtra("id", id);
            intent.putExtra("time", time2.getText().toString());
            PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(MainActivity.this, id, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

            alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, System.currentTimeMillis(), 60 * 1000, pi);
        }
    }); 
    button3.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent intent = new Intent("com.newitventure.remainder.START");
            int id = (int) System.currentTimeMillis();
            intent.setClass(MainActivity.this, ServiceRestarterBroadcastReceivers.class);
            intent.putExtra("id", id);
            intent.putExtra("time", time3.getText().toString());
            PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(MainActivity.this, id, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

            alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, System.currentTimeMillis(), 60 * 1000, pi);
        }
    }); 
    button4.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent intent = new Intent("com.newitventure.remainder.START");
            int id = (int) System.currentTimeMillis();
            intent.setClass(MainActivity.this, ServiceRestarterBroadcastReceivers.class);
            intent.putExtra("id", id);
            intent.putExtra("time", time4.getText().toString());
            PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(MainActivity.this, id, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

            alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, System.currentTimeMillis(), 60 * 1000, pi);
        }
    }); 
    button5.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent intent = new Intent("com.newitventure.remainder.START");
            int id = (int) System.currentTimeMillis();
            intent.setClass(MainActivity.this, ServiceRestarterBroadcastReceivers.class);
            intent.putExtra("id", id);
            intent.putExtra("time", time5.getText().toString());
            PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(MainActivity.this, id, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

            alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, System.currentTimeMillis(), 60 * 1000, pi);
        }
    }); 
    button6.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent intent = new Intent("com.newitventure.remainder.START");
            int id = (int) System.currentTimeMillis();
            intent.setClass(MainActivity.this, ServiceRestarterBroadcastReceivers.class);
            intent.putExtra("id", id);
            intent.putExtra("time", time6.getText().toString());
            PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(MainActivity.this, id, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

            alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, System.currentTimeMillis(), 60 * 1000, pi);
        }
    });

  }
}
```

*ServiceRestarterBroadcastReceivers.java*

```
public class ServiceRestarterBroadcastReceivers extends BroadcastReceiver {

Context context;
long millis;

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

    this.context = context;

    String action = intent.getAction();

    if (action.equalsIgnoreCase("com.newitventure.remainder.STOP_SERVICE")) {
        context.stopService(intent);
    } else {
        final String programTime = intent.getStringExtra("time");
        final int id = intent.getIntExtra("id", 0);

        millis = System.currentTimeMillis();

        calculateMinute(programTime, id);

    }

}

private void calculateMinute(String programTime, int id) {

    SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm");
    Date startTime = new Date();
    Date endTime = new Date();

    try {
        startTime = simpleDateFormat.parse(simpleDateFormat.format(millis));
        endTime = simpleDateFormat.parse(programTime);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    long difference = endTime.getTime() - startTime.getTime();

    if (difference < 0) {
        Date dateMax = new Date();
        Date dateMin = new Date();
        try {
            dateMax = simpleDateFormat.parse("24:00");

            dateMin = simpleDateFormat.parse("00:00");

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        difference = (dateMax.getTime() - startTime.getTime()) + (endTime.getTime() - dateMin.getTime());
    }

    String hour = String.format("%02d", TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toHours(difference));
    String inMins = String.format("%02d", TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(difference) - TimeUnit.HOURS.toMinutes(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toHours(difference)));
    Log.d("lala", "onCreate: min" + hour + " " + inMins);

    if (hour.equalsIgnoreCase("00")) {
        if (inMins.equalsIgnoreCase("05")) {
                Intent background = new Intent(context, AlarmServiceClass.class);
                background.putExtra("time", programTime);
                background.putExtra("id", id);
                if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
                    context.startForegroundService(background);
                } else {
                    context.startService(background);
                }
        }
    }
}
}
```

*AlarmServiceClass.java*

```
public class AlarmServiceClass extends Service {

long millis;
int id;
String programTime;
Notification notification;
NotificationManager notificationManager;
IntentFilter intentFilter;


@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();

    Log.d("lala", "onCreate: ");
    notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    return START_STICKY;

}

private void showNotification(String programTime, int id) {

    RemoteViews views = new RemoteViews(getPackageName(), R.layout.notification);

    String CHANNEL_ID = "2018";
    CharSequence channelName = "Vinay";

    Intent recentIntent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
    recentIntent.setAction("com.newitventure.remainder.STOP_SERVICE");
    recentIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
    PendingIntent pendInt = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, id,
            recentIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);

    views.setTextViewText(R.id.text, programTime);

    notification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
            .setCustomContentView(views)
            .setContentIntent(pendInt)
            .setAutoCancel(true)
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher_foreground)
            .setChannelId(CHANNEL_ID)
            .build();


    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
        NotificationChannel channel = new NotificationChannel(CHANNEL_ID,
                channelName, NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_LOW);
        channel.setSound(null, null); 
        notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(channel);
    }

    startForeground(id, notification);
  }
}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51262739/show-multiple-notification#new-answer
Have you found the solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution to my problem. Instead of starting service using `startForeground(id, notification)` I used `notificationManager.notify(id, notification)` and voila! it worked. I get all the 6 notifications.

But problem still exists when I want to show notification even if the app is killed from the recent apps. Android Oreo restricts app from showing background notification so it forces me to use `startForeground(id, notification)`. Hence I am back to square one. Anyone??

Comment: Have you found out the solution?